# how can I make my drop down menu not disappear after the 1st list item?

Tags: css, html

I have a drop down menu with 3 sub list items in every tab, there's a problem were the drop down menu disappears when you move the mouse to the second drop down menu list item. Any idea on how to fix this? I tired setting .sub-nav to display block on hover also but this didnt work, any ideas as to why?

```css
nav {
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
nav li > span,
nav a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
nav ul {
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 5% 0 0;
}
nav li {
  max-height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.main-nav:hover {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a {
  color: orange;
}
.home-page a:visited {
  color: white;
}
nav a:visited {
  color: orange;
}
.active {
  background-color: #ffcc33;
}
.main-nav {
  position: relative;
}
.sub-nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.sub-nav {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.main-nav:hover .sub-nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="main-nav home-page active">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main-nav">
      <span> Content 1 </span>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-nav">
      <span> Content 2 </span>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page6.html">Page 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main-nav">
      <span> Content 3 </span>
      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="page7.html">Page 7</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page 8</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="page1.html">Page 9</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have a max-height set to all ul's within your nav. If you remove this then it'll work fine.

```
  nav ul {
    max-height: 100%; <-- here
    text-align: right;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 5% 0 0;
    }
```

If you need max-height then just apply it to the first child of nav (nav > ul).

```
nav > ul {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Codepen example - http://codepen.io/lukemeaden/pen/mPGreY

Comment: its workng like it should now, Thanks that solved it,  that brings up a another question though, if I had that set to max height how and why was the sub ul outside the li element that was its parent, if I set something to max-height: 100% doesnt mean the element cant go above or under the element? I'm a bit confused on this because the sub nav was most outside its parent element the main-nav li

Comment: @Brandon I believe it's because the sub ui was overflowing from it's parent that the cursor then ignored it. Glad it's sorted!